# How to use the timestamp in mahout (taste)? (Using Java)

Tags: java, mahout

I need to add timestamp(movielens dataset) into the slope-one algorithm to make it more accurate.

I thought I should modify the source code([MemoryDiffStorage.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/tags/mahout-0.4/core/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/impl/recommender/slopeone/MemoryDiffStorage.java) in mahout-core/...cf/taste/impl/recommender/slopeone), but I don't know how add the timestamp.

Even though I found the definition `Long getPreferenceTime(long userID, long itemID)` in [DataModle.java](http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/mahout/tags/mahout-0.4/core/src/main/java/org/apache/mahout/cf/taste/model/DataModel.java), I still have no idea about it.

I should say I am new to Java and Mahout. So explain to me in detail please! Thanks~ :)

Add modified code below:) Original code is in MemoryDiffStorage.java, I just plug some statements in. I wonder if I plug in wrong place,but I thought this is where it gets values.

```
private long processOneUser(long averageCount, long userID) throws TasteException {
log.debug("Processing prefs for user {}", userID);
// Save off prefs for the life of this loop iteration
PreferenceArray userPreferences = dataModel.getPreferencesFromUser(userID);
int length = userPreferences.length();

for (int i = 0; i < length - 1; i++) {
  float prefAValue = userPreferences.getValue(i);
  long itemIDA = userPreferences.getItemID(i);
  long Timestamp = dataModel.getPreferenceTime(userID, itemIDA);
  long timestamp_max = 1046388675;
  long timestamp_min = 975042787;
  long t = (Timestamp - timestamp_min)/(timestamp_max - timestamp_min);
  prefAValue = prefAValue * t;
  FastByIDMap<RunningAverage> aMap = averageDiffs.get(itemIDA);
  if (aMap == null) {
    aMap = new FastByIDMap<RunningAverage>();
    averageDiffs.put(itemIDA, aMap);
  }
  for (int j = i + 1; j < length; j++) {
    // This is a performance-critical block
    long itemIDB = userPreferences.getItemID(j);
    RunningAverage average = aMap.get(itemIDB);
    if (average == null && averageCount < maxEntries) {
      average = buildRunningAverage();
      aMap.put(itemIDB, average);
      averageCount++;
    }
    if (average != null) {
      average.addDatum(userPreferences.getValue(j) - prefAValue);
    }
  }
```

Comment: You've found methods that provide the timestamp... what do you mean that you can't use them?

Comment: @SeanOwen Thank you for your comment. I mean I don't know how to use it.(I'm not sure if my English could be understood by natives) I've modified the source codes but it made no change in results.

Comment: You use it by getting timestamp information and using that in your algorithm. How you do that is up to you. The framework itself does not use timestamp.

Comment: @SeanOwen So I should create my own algorithm in my own project but not try to revise the mahout source code, is that right? Thank you again~